# jquery way to get property value inside style attribute when property key exist?

Tags: jquery, properties, styles, inline

```
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; font-size: 12; right:400px; top:100px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; font-size: 14; right:200px; top:140px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

I wanted to do something like

```
var positionvalue= $('.test'). get value where position is exist inside style attribute  
var topvalue= $('.test'). get value where top is exist inside style attribute.
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this via jquery?

meaning no need to read the style into variable, then split into array of array, the loop through to compare property key to get value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Top, use this

```
$('.test').position().top
```

*Example: Returns **100***

To get position, use this

```
$('.test').css('position')
```

*Example: Returns **absolute***

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/3Xu3b/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link of the JQuery API [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

As mentioned above you code would be :-

```
var topvalue= $('.test').position.top;
```